# Is "you are yourself" grammatically correct?

Tags: be

I know what "be yourself" means. I usually see people using it in some sentences like "You have to be yourself", "You must be yourself" etc., but I barely see anyone saying "You are yourself".

Is that sentence correct? I used it in this below context when I tried to define what a friend is

"Friend is someone you have a bond with. You feel comfortable and are yourself when you are with them."

If it is wrong, how could I correct it, particularly in the context?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! You might find [the English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) a valuable resource.

Comment: Good question! There’s nothing ungrammatical about it, but you’re right that we don’t generally use the simple present construction here – it does sound a bit ‘off’ somehow. I can’t really see any reason why this should be so, but I feel fairly confident that it is. The most common way to phrase the sense that you have here would be to say that a friend [note: indefinite article is required] is someone you feel comfortable and _can be_ yourself around.

Comment: Thanks!!! I just joined here and did not expect to get a reply so fast.

Comment: This is a little out of scope, but for the sake of grammatically correct.
As [friend](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/friend?q=friend) is a countable noun, an article is needed.
"A friend is someone you have a bond with."

Comment: It’s a tautology but it’s grammatically correct. In the context you’ve given “you can be yourself when you are with them” is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the entry of "be oneself" from Oxford Living Dictionary https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/be_oneself,

you can define "friend" like this:

"A friend is someone you have a bond with. You ***feel comfortable and act naturally, according to your character and instincts*** when you are with them".

As about saying "You are yourself", I can give you some examples from https://context.reverso.net:

- I see from your letter that you are yourself the daughter of a country parson.
- You are yourself again.
- See...? You are yourself again.

Answer (score 1):

> "Friend is someone you have a bond with. You feel comfortable and are
>   yourself when you are with them."

I would say "and you can be yourself"